# Unable to delete row from SQLite DB via delete() - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-delete

I have a sqlite db with 3 tables. TABLE1, TABLE2 and TABLE3.

I am using the following API to delete row(s) from the DB:

```
int rowsAffected = db.delete(tableName, "columnName=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(shoeId)});
```

Now, when I run this API for TABLE1 and TABLE2, the rows get deleted fine and I get the correct number in rowsAffected. But when i used this API for TABLE3, I always get `rowsAffected` as 0 and no entries are deleted.

```
int rowsAffected = db.delete(tableName, "columnName=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(shoeId)});
```

All 3 tables have the shoeId column.

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: have you check which shoeId you get and pass is contain that table

Comment: have you give any foreignkey?

Comment: the delete method should not look like `int delete (String table, String whereClause,  String[] whereArgs)` ? But you seems to put the name of your table into the constraint. So this should result into a query like `"DELETE FROM" + tableName + "WHERE TABLE3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above query was not working due to the following reasons:

- Lets say the columnName here is busTicketId and its data type is Int.
- When the DB was created, the busTicketId was erroneously created as default String type due to an error in the Create table query.
- As a result when the time came to delete busTicketId, it was trying to search for busTicketId, which was of Int type and since it could not find any, the rows affected count always turned out to be 0.

Once the data type issue for this column was fixed while creating the table, this issue also got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is the where clause, so you query should look like this :

```
int rowsAffected = db.delete(tableName, "nameOfColumn=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(shoeId)});
```

This means : `"DELETE FROM tableName WHERE nameOfColumn = String.valueOf(shoeId)"`

Don't remove the `=?`, it is used for prepared statements

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo. The actual code did have =? next to the columnName.